# Problem with justifying the validity of integrating the both sides of an equation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

I am having problem with justifying the validity of integrating the both sides of a PDE and then solving for the unknowns. For example, say I want to solve for x in the following:
$$   
\frac{d(x^{2})}{dx}=x^{3}
$$

Method $1$: $$\frac{d(x^{2})}{dx}\ \text{is}\ 2x$$ Hence, $2x = x^{3}$ which gives $x = 0, \pm \sqrt{2}$

Method $2$: Integrate both sides for the equation from $0$ to $x$:
$$
x^{2}-0=\frac{x^{4}}{4}-0
$$
Hence, $x = 0, \pm2$

Why are these two approaches giving different answers? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have shown by method 1 that your equation only holds for 3 values of $x$. Integral of a function defined on an interval is possible, but  you don't have such a function. Method 2 cannot be used, has no meaning. You should remove the PDE tag, please.

Comment: The tag has been removed.